# Is there any good sample about facebook-php-sdk3.0+ with CodeIgniter2.0+?

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I use CodeIgniter2.0.3 and facebook-php-sdk3.1.1 to develop an application.

When I run the project,is says:

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Facebook in ../application/libraries/facebook.php on line 24**

The source of line 24 is:

```
class Facebook extends BaseFacebook
```

What's the reason?How to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the name of your controller. If it is called Facebook then that is your problem, you cannot have 2 classes called the same thing at once, unless they are in different namespaces.

I wouldn't suggest using the normal Facebook PHP-SDK when there are a number available over [on codeigniter sparks](http://getsparks.org/) that perform most of the same functions but already setup to work with codeigniter without these conflicts.

Comment: Your answer is right.It was the controller name's problem.And also thank you for showing me the codeigniter sparks.